# how to get data from object type in jsonserialization in swift 5

Tags: json, swift, serialization

Want to get this data with json serialization `{"id":1,"name":"harry"}`

I have tried this method but getting error(Method not allowed) `let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)`

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
    print(json)
}
task.resume()
```

result should be something like this : `{"id":1,"name":"harry"}`

Comment: You forgot `do - catch` around the `try` line.

Comment: sorry I used it ..not mention in this question... getting this error in catch

Comment: Please edit the question and add the real code. This *pseudo* code shows an error about an unwrapped optional, nothing else. And delete the `options` parameter. `allowFragments` is pointless anyway if the expected object is a collection type.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use `JSONSerialization`? You can use `Codable` for that easily.

Comment: any example... @PGDev

Comment: @BaluSama I've added an answer below. Check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `JSONSerialization`, try using **`Codable`** to parse the *JSON response* using the below *model*.

**Model:**

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

**Parsing:**

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
    if let data = data {
        do {
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            print(response)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Now, you can use the `response` object to access the `id` and name `properties`.

Comment: Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set


getting this error

Comment: The error clearly indicates that the received data is not JSON. Most likely it's HTML

Comment: so how I can see this response ... :(

Comment: `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)`

Comment: actually html data in return ..thats why this error... but still working on this problem. will come back to stack overflow